# Theory: LL(k) parser vs parser for LL(k) grammars

Tags: parsing, grammar, theory

I'm concerned about the very important difference between the therms: "`LL(k)` parser" and "parser for `LL(k)` grammars". When a `LL(1)` backtracking parser is in question, it **IS** a parser for `LL(k)` grammars, because it can parse them, but its **NOT** `LL(k)` parser, because it does not use `k` tokens to look ahead from a single position in the grammar, but its exploring with backtracking the possible cases, regardless that it still uses `k` tokens to explore.
Am I right?

The question may break down to the way the look-ahead is performed. If the look-ahead is actually still processing the grammar with backtracking, that does not make it `LL(k)` parser. To be `LL(k)` parser the parser must not use the grammar with backtracking mechanism, because then it would be "`LL(1)` parser with backtracking that can parser `LL(k)` grammars".
Am I right again?

I think the difference is related to the expectation that `LL(1)` parser is using a `constant` time per token, and `LL(k)` parser is using at most `k * constant` (linear to the look-ahead) time per token, **not** an `exponential time` as it would be in the case of a backtracking parser.

Update 1: to simplify - per token, is the parsing `LL(k)` expected to run exponentially in respect to `k` or in a linear time in respect to `k`?

Update 2: I have changed it to `LL(k)` because the question is irrelevant to the range of which `k` is (integer or infinity).

Comment: It's not possible to answer a question about "backtracking LL(1) parsers" unless you precisely define a backtracking algorithm (and even then it will be difficult to do the analysis). I provided a new answer which only talks about LL(k) grammars; I hope it answers your question listed in "Update 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the chapter 5.1 of Aho Ullman Volume 1.

https://dl.acm.org/doi/book/10.5555/578789

1. A LL(k) parser is a k-predictive algorithm (k is the lookahead integer >= 1).
2. A LL(k) parser can parse any LL(k) grammar. (chapter 5.1.2)
3. for all a, b you have a < b => LL(b) grammar is also a LL(a) grammar. But the reverse is not true.
4. A LL(k) parser is PREDICTIVE. So there is NO backtracking.
5. All LL(k) parsers are O(n) n is the length of the parsed sentence.
6. It is important to understand that a LL(3) parser do not parse faster than a LL(1). But the LL(3) parser can parse MORE grammars than the LL(1). (see the point #2 and #3)

Answer (score 2):

An LL(k) parser needs to do the following at each point in the inner loop:

- Collect the next *k* input symbols. Since this is done at each point in the input, this can be done in constant time by keeping the lookahead vector in a circular buffer.
- If the top of the prediction stack is a terminal, then it is compared with the next input symbol; either both are discarded or an error is signalled. This is clearly constant time.
- If the top of the prediction stack is a non-terminal, the action table is consulted, using the non-terminal, the current state and the current lookahead vector as keys. (Not all LL(k) parsers need to maintain a state; this is the most general formulation. But it doesn't make a difference to complexity.) This lookup can also be done in constant time, again by taking advantage of the incremental nature of the lookahead vector.
- The prediction action is normally done by pushing the right-hand side of the selected production onto the stack. A naive implementation would take time proportional to the length of the right-hand side, which is not correlated with either the lookahead `k` nor the length of the input `N`, but rather is related to the size of the grammar itself. It's possible to avoid the variability of this work by simply pushing a reference to the right-hand side, which can be used as though it were the list of symbols (since the list can't change during the parse).

  However, that's not the full story. Executing a prediction action does not consume an input, and it's possible -- even likely -- that multiple predictions will be made for a single input symbol. Again, the maximum number of predictions is only related to the grammar itself, not to `k` nor to `N`.

  More specifically, since the same non-terminal cannot be predicted twice in the same place without violating the LL property, the total number of predictions cannot exceed the number of non-terminals in the grammar. Therefore, even if you do push the entire right-hand side onto the stack, the total number of symbols pushed between consecutive shift actions cannot exceed the size of the grammar. (Each right-hand side can be pushed at most once. In fact, only one right-hand side for a given non-terminal can be pushed, but it's possible that almost every non-terminal has only one right-hand side, so that doesn't reduce the asymptote.) If instead only a reference is pushed onto the stack, the number of objects pushed between consecutive shift actions -- that is, the number of predict actions between two consecutive shift actions -- cannot exceed the size of the non-terminal alphabet. (But, again, it's possible that `|V|` is `O(|G|)`.

The linearity of LL(k) parsing was established, I believe, in Lewis and Stearns (1968), but I don't have that paper at hand right now so I'll refer you to the proof in Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen's *Parsing Theory* (1988), where it is proved in Chapter 5 for Strong LL(K) (as defined by [Rosenkrantz & Stearns 1970](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870904468)), and in Chapter 8 for Canonical LL(K).

In short, the time the LL(k) algorithm spends between shifting two successive input symbols is expected to be `O(|G|)`, which is independent of both `k` and `N` (and, of course, constant for a given grammar).

This does not really have any relation to `LL(*)` parsers, since an `LL(*)` parser does not just try successive `LL(k)` parses (which would not be possible, anyway). For the `LL(*)` algorithm presented by Terence Parr (which is the only reference I know of which defines what `LL(*)` means), there is no bound to the amount of time which could be taken between successive shift actions. The parser might expand the lookahead to the entire remaining input (which would, therefore, make the time complexity dependent on the total size of the input), or it might fail over to a backtracking algorithm, in which case it is more complicated to define what is meant by "processing an input symbol".

Comment: That is very nice explanation, but... if a parser operates with this stack model, per `k` tokens (not one), at a single starting position, it will actually perform a depth recursive search in the grammar by "expanding" the non terminals, which can be exponential in relation to k (non deterministic pushdown automata for non left recursive CFG). And there is the issue. When there is no left recursion, then the time is upper bounded by the grammar (non linear to the grammar size however), true that, but this does not make the total work constant, its still exponential, just upper bounded.

Comment: @verbessern: fortunately, there is a simple alternative which controls the stack size. You don't really have to push a copy of the RHS; just a reference to a point in the RHS. So that's O(1). You can still do a shift action in constant time by updating the reference to the next point. There is a proof that this leads to linear-total-tlme parsing if the grammar is LL(k).

Comment: I can add a reference if you like. The proof itself is too long for an SO answer.

Comment: I don't think so. Please do add. However its not about pushing this single item, its about expanding it until a token can be recognized. This is only part of the full step per token, and yes its O(1), but that is not the total work done per `k` symbols. Its even not the total work done per one symbol, its just a part (small of many) of the work done for a single symbol.

Comment: This what you have described, is in fact pushdown automata per symbol. I think that LL(k) parser is not working as a pushdown automata, even that a pushdown automata can recognize LL(k) grammars, and there is my problem, that led to this question. I think that, a true LL(k) parser will perform linearly per `k` for each symbol, else it does not make sense to have two terms for the same thing (pushdown automata vs LL(k)).

Comment: @verbessern: They're not the same thing, really. For one thing, many PDAs recognise languages which are not LL(k) for any k. For another thing, the LL(k) parser has a lookahead buffer of k symbols, which is not part of the formal definition of a PDA (although it doesn't really add anything, since the LL(k) parser uses the lookahead buffer the way the PDA uses it's state, and you could convert between the two models by running the PDA k symbols ahead, translating each input symbol into a state transition by mapping the k-strings onto the states.

Comment: Sippu & Soisalon-Soininen do make a distinction between a PDA -- which can *recognise* a sentence in the associated grammar -- and a parser; the parser has to also record the derivation steps in order to be able to build the parse tree. The LL(k) algorithm they propose is implemented with a pushdown transducer. But again, pushdown transducers -- even deterministic PDTs -- are more powerful than LL(k) grammars. (They can parse any LR language.)

Comment: You have described PDA in this answer, and you do claim that its linear, because some of its steps are constant, but that is not enough to be linear. PDA is exponential in fact. I can't accept that, because its simply not true. Here, one way of having a PDA is recursive descent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869453/on-complexity-of-recursive-descent-parsers

Comment: The use of memoization may help, but that is shifting the complexity from the algorithm to the size of the used memory, and is not the essence of my question.

Comment: Oh, the answer was edited, I have to read the articles first. Anyway the part you explain that because the RHS is pushed one time in constant time, is not a prove of linearity, as I said before. That is only one step of many, because the RHS must be continuously expanded, until a token is on top. That is exactly what PDA does often as RD parser, which are exponential in time, not linear.

Comment: @verbessern: PDAs are linear, not exponential. Only backtracking creates exponential complexity, and LL(k) parsing doesn't require backtracking precisely because the PDA is deterministic. The grammar in the answer to the question you link to is not an LL(k) grammar, so it's not a counterexample.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221867/discussion-between-verbessern-and-rici).

Comment: @verbessern: i'm ok to chat but I'm in UTC-5. I addressed the issue of repetitive expansion of RHSs: if the same non-terminal shows up twice in an expansion sequence without a shift then the grammar is not LL. (Because it is indirectly left-recursive). So the expansion time is O(|G|), which is not exponential, not related to N, and not related to k.

Comment: That is true for the left recursive grammars. But you are still talking for LL(1) expansion of the RHS. When the parser is LL(k) and you expand your RHS per token in the way you described you may exhibit exponential expansion time in relation to `k`. I cannot accept that. I'm unable to find the cited articles and I'm not willing to buy books that "maybe" have a prove. I cannot accept an answer when the actual answer is not available. Also the articles seems to be related to Greibach normal form, which has related conversion times from a general CFG.

Comment: @verbessern: There is no difference between a predict action in LL(1), LL(2) or LL(100). The predict action simply predicts which production will be applied. With an LL(k) grammar, the prediction is 100% correct, so there is never any backtracking. To do that you need a table of predictions by lookahead; the *size* of this table is exponential in `k`, but that shouldn't affect the lookup time. (It might affect the practical implementation, but that's a different story.) The table is precomputed and the computation time is not counted as part of the parse time...

Comment: But I think we're probably talking at cross-purposes here. I don't believe there is such a thing as an "LL(k) parse of a non-LL(k) grammar". If a grammar is not LL(k), then there simply is no LL(k) parser. You can try applying a different algorithm, perhaps involving backtracking, but in that case you have no reason to choose any particular fixed value of *k*, so again the details of the LL(k) algorithm don't seem to me to be relevant.

Comment: Throughout, I have been using the standard definition of "LL(k)", as found in pretty well any text on compiler theory. Definitions are not absolute, of course; there is no divine authority for defining terms and everyone is free to use whatever terms they chose, defined as they see fit. But if you use an unfamiliar definition of a familiar term, you do have some obligation to define what you mean by it. (And if you do so precisely enough, no-one can complain, however idiosyncratic the result is.)

Comment: As I have explained multiple times, the description you have provided (PDA) is explaining how the parser will operated by searching in-depth. That search, as you have defined is exponential (like you have confirmed yourself up for the size of the search field), but you still write linear in the answer. I cannot click accept on this, because its not true. Also, if you start to "reuse" definitions, you practically spoil the terminology, because people read it, and they start to distribute it, even when its not valid.

Comment: @verbessern: the table's *size* is exponential in k. But the table's contents are precomputed during parser construction. And there is no need to linearly search the table; the lookup time is constant regardless of the table's size. It's not a search; just an indexed lookup.

Comment: That I can accept, because aligns with my other knowledge, but the answer does not have it. It has PDA, that is not how LL(k) is done, but how the search space could be per-recomputed (table), else if you actually run as it is in the answer, its LL(1) RD with backtracking. As I see, even a person with a lot of knowledge can mix both, so the question was not trivial.

Comment: @verbessern: [Rosenkrantz & Stearns 1970](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870904468) appears to not be paywalled today.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything in my answer which could possibly be interpreted as implying that an LL(k) parse involves backtracking. The only mention of backtracking is at the end in reference to LL(*) parsing, which is completely different. If that was confusing, I apologise.